# Dedup rows with case insensitive (Snowflake)

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I would like to dedup rows when there are multiple instances.

original table:

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple |
| 2 | Banana |
| 1 | apple |
| 2 | APPLE |
| 3 | BANANA |

desired output after deduping (prioritize lowercase when there are multiple cases):

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | Banana |
| 1 | apple |
| 2 | apple |
| 3 | Banana |

The ID 1 "Apple" was removed because ID 1 "apple" exists.
The ID 2 "APPLE" becomes "apple" because there is ID 1 "apple".
The ID 3 "BANANA" became "Banana" because lowercase is priority.

Following statement only works for group by ID.  Therefore, the ID 2 "APPLE" stays "APPLE" and ID 3 "BANANA" stays "BANANA" that is not desirable.

```
create table DELETE2 as select ID, max(Name) as Name
FROM TEST."PUBLIC"."DELETE1"
group by ID, lower(Name);

drop table DELETE1;
alter table DELETE2 rename to DELETE1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working SQL you can paste into Snowflake and run:

Technique ... make all words into array of chars -> turn each char into ascii ... sum ascii. little letters have higher ascii than caps.

No updates ... no functions ... just plain old SQL ;-)
[image]

```
with cte as (
select  1 ID, 'Apple' name
union select 2 ID, 'Banana' name
union select  1 ID, 'apple' name
union select 2 ID, 'APPLE' name
union select 3 ID, 'BANANA' name ),
lu as (
select
    name,
    lower (name) lu_name,
    sum(ascii(a.value :: string)) ac,
    max(ac) over (partition by lower(name)) mac,
    iff (  max(ac) over (partition by lower(name)) = sum(ascii(a.value :: string)),name, null) g
from
    cte,
    lateral flatten(
        input => split(regexp_replace(name, '.', ',\\0', 2), ',')
    ) a
group by  1,2
)
select
cte.id, lu.name
from
cte
left outer join lu on lower(cte.name) = lu.lu_name and lu.g is not null
group by  1, 2
```

[image]

Comment: Cte = ur starting table, lu is a lookup table that works out the correct label for each fruit. It does this by turning each letter into ASCII and summing. The sum with the max is the label with most number of lower letters. This means it will choose appLE over apPLE . The final sql just puts things together.   Make sense?

Comment: CTE and LU are Common Table Expressions … not actual tables more like temporary views.  You could make them tables if u prefer.

Comment: Thank you Adrian.  The output is what I'm looking for.

I'm still a beginner of snowflake and trying to understand your code.
1. with cte as ...lu as ... --> is this for temporary creating a table?
2. sum(ascii(a.value :: string)) ac,
    max(ac) over (partition by lower(name)) mac,
    iff (  max(ac) over (partition by lower(name)) = sum(ascii(a.value :: string)),name, null) g --> what does this code do?
3.  lateral flatten(
        input => split(regexp_replace(name, '.', ',\\0', 2), ',')
    ) a --> what does this code do?
4. group by  1,2 --> what tables are 1 & 2?

Comment: sum(ascii(a.value :: string)) ac, max(ac) over (partition by lower(name))  : This sums up the ascii values used for each word.  I partition by lower(name) so all the apples and bananas are compared within fruit type not across all fruits.

Comment: iff ( max(ac) over (partition by lower(name)) = sum(ascii(a.value :: string)),name, null) g ... This just compares the best value for apple against the current value for apple. Meaning if you add more records it will automatically keep working.  Basically just telling me this record is the best label for each fruit type.

Comment: Group by 1,2 means group by column 1 which is ID and column 2 which is Name. You can replace group by 1,2 with group by ID, NAME.  Group by groups identical values of separate rows into a single value on a single row

Comment: Now to be honest if you're new to SQL this is an extremely complex thing to start on.    I'd recommend you try some free courses on the snowflake website that take you step by step through things ...

Comment: regexp_replace(name, '.', ',\\0', 2) - so for each 'name' of fruit I want to split the chars into separate values and get their ascii equivalent then sum that lot up to get the 'name' with the most little letters.   the SPLIT/regex combo does this. Once summed I then want to get the max sum for each fruit type.   I'd really try to get to grips with CTE's and basic SQL before this part.  This is like the ultimate test of stack overflow :-).

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation, Adrian!  I will watch and try some free courses on the snowflake website first.  Is there anything else do you recommend to do in order to improve the snowflake skills and become an expert like you?

Comment: https://snowflakeuniversity.mindtickle.com/ is quite good.  I'm new to Snowflake as well (less than 6 months) ... just did the basic courses here and then tried answering SO questions with explanations. This teaches me heaps.  Everyone's a beginner as Snowflake literally releases new stuff each week ... cool place to be at the moment :-)

Comment: Awesome.  I will try their training courses. Thanks again, Adrian!

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
create table DELETE2 as 
select ID, Name
from (
        select ID, lower(Name) as Name1, max(Name) as Name
        FROM TEST."PUBLIC"."DELETE1"
        group by ID, lower(Name)
     )
;
```

Comment: Does that get the desired outcome ... that's both 1 and 2 versions of Apple showing 'apple' ?

Comment: Thank you @NickW.  However, the ID 2 "APPLE" still stays "APPLE" and ID 3 "BANANA" still stays "BANANA" using this method.