# Find unique routes in sql

Tags: sql

I have a table route with 2 columns, source and destination. And I want to find out the unique routes.

```
Sample Input for route table -
-------------
src    dest
-------------
A       B
C       D
B       A
D       C

Required output -
-------------
src    dest
-------------
A       B
C       D
```

In this case, AB and BA are the same route, just that the src and dest changes, so we only show that in the output once. Any inputs to solve this problem would be helpful.

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: What are you doing so far and into which problem did you run?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just a little logic switch would do

**Example**

```
Select Distinct 
        case when src < dest then src  else dest end as src
      , case when src < dest then dest else src  end as dest
  From  YourTable
```

**Results**

```
src dest
A   B
C   D
```

Comment: This is a fine answer but (1) it is not optimal if all pairs are in the data with inverses and (2) if not, the the results may not be the pair in the original data.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest:

```
select src, dest
from t t2
where src < dest or
      not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.src < t2.dest and t2.src = t.dest and t2.dest = t.src);
```

Note:  This is guaranteed to return only pairs that are in the table.  If you know that all "reversals" are in the table (as in your sample data), then it is simply:

```
select src, dest
from t
where src < dest;
```

Comment: Would this run faster than just summing the ascii's

Comment: @AdrianWhite . . . I don't know what that comment means.

Comment: @AdrianWhite and Gordon.  Perhaps this will clear-up the confusion. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=486e3aa85705ffc3f3e74660f4612695

Comment: @AdrianWhite No they are not the same..  Please look again.  Both yours and Gordon's exclude the added Albany.

Comment: Replacing 'Albany' with 'P' or any single char as the question kind of alluded to keeps all three answers correct.  However you're correct if you alter the datatype from char(1) to char(x) the solution would need to be different.

Comment: Would never put "nonsensical" and "Gordon Linoff" in the same sentence.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti . . . I appreciate that -- a lot.  However, the original answer was only half of what I intended.  I left out the correlation clause.  It is not enough for me to "think of the answer".  I also need to get it out in some comprehensible form!

Answer (score 1):

Simplest with [`GREATEST` and `LEAST`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-GREATEST-LEAST):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT GREATEST(src, dest) AS a, LEAST(src, dest) AS b
FROM   tbl;
```

Logically equivalent to [John's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68238616/939860) with `CASE`, **except** for the corner case where one of both is `NULL`. In **Postgres** you get the not-null value twice with this query. [Quoting the manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-GREATEST-LEAST)

> Note that `GREATEST` and `LEAST` are not in the SQL standard, but are
> a common extension. Some other databases make them return `NULL` if any
> argument is `NULL`, rather than only when all are `NULL`.

You may have to adapt if there *can* be `NULL` values.

Comment: Although as you state the GREATEST/LEAST are not compatible with say SQL Server .. I like your approach for it's efficiency and simplicity.  Personally I'd see a MIN/MAX  as more simple and clear but DISTINCT GREATEST is far superior to the hard coding  switch statements approaches. It also handles varchar(x) which the min/max does not. And from someone with more than 100K status points ... all is not lost on SO.

Comment: @AdrianWhite: Note that Postgres would handle `varchar(x)` in `CASE` or with `min()`/`max()` , too, as the required operators are defined for the type. `GREATEST`/`LEAST` is just simpler. Not even much faster, if at all.

Answer (score 0):

Using the ascii function makes things flow somewhat nicer for the optimiser and visually in the sql.

```
select 
    min(src) src 
   ,max(dst) dst 
from 
    cte 
group by 
   (ascii(src) + ascii(dst))
```

[image]

Side note this assumes the src/dst are char(1) as shown in the question. If this turns into a varchar(x) then I'd sum all ascii's in the varchar() as demonstrated in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68220629/dedup-rows-with-case-insensitive-snowflake/68221890#68221890)